# Grep the lines between the occurrence of the same pattern

Tags: awk, grep

I would like to grep the lines between the same occurrence of a pattern and then save each matching lines in a different file.
For example, I have this:

```
name
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
name
aaa1
bbb1
ccc1
name
...
```

I would like to have

```
name
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
```

in file1

```
name
aaa1
bbb1
ccc1
```

in file 2, and so on.

I tried with a flag inversion in awk like that:

```
awk '/^name/ {flag=!flag; next} flag {print}'
```

but I'm not getting what I want.

Do you have any suggestion to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
awk '/name/{n+=1}{print > "file_"n".txt"}'
```

Which will produce `file_1.txt`, `file_2.txt`... etc

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my day. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the "csplit" for this purpose as in:

```
csplit yourfile -s -n 1 -f file_ '%name%' '/name/' '{*}'
```

This will produce files "file_1", "file_2", etc.