# Counting the number of lines between same repeating pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have refer this [Grep the lines between the occurrence of the same pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346203/grep-the-lines-between-the-occurrence-of-the-same-pattern) , I don't want to split into file; instead, I want to store it into an array. File `count.txt` contain:

```
0 
1
2
3
0
1
2
0
1
```

My script code is:

```
total=$(sed -n \$= count.txt)
c=0
k=0
lineno=0
var="0"
for i in $(cat count.txt);
do
        if ["$i" -eq "$var"]
        then
                arr[$((k++))]=c
                c=0
                c=$((c+1))

        else
                c=$((c+1))
                if ["$lineno" -eq "$total"]
                then
                        arr[$((k++))]=c
                fi
        fi
        lineno=$((lineno+1))
done
```

The above logic is tested on C++ launguage which on printing the array shows : `0 4 3 2`
Firstly, my script is showing error like `line 9: [0: command not found`.
Secondly, is there any efficient method to store the repeated count in array, like above output?

Comment: The `command not found` error is because your `[` test lacks the required whitespace: `[ "$i" -eq "$var" ]`

Comment: @msp9011 I want the output: 4 3 2 in array

Comment: There is not output instruction; in addition `=c` is putting the letter c in the variable, may be you want `=$c` and the first test is right the first time as `0=0` this explains the potential output 0 in sequence instead of `4 3 2`.

Answer (score 1):

An awk one-liner:

```
awk -v patt="0" -v prev=1 '
    $0 ~ patt {print NR - prev; prev = NR} 
    END {print NR + 1 - prev}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
LINES=(`cat count.txt `)
arr=()
arrIndex=0
a=`echo $LINES`
for i in "${!LINES[@]}"; do
if [[ "${LINES[$i]}" = "$a" ]]; then
        arr[arrIndex]=`echo "${i}"`
        arrIndex=$((arrIndex+1))
fi
done
arr[arrIndex]=`echo ${#LINES[@]}`
arrOut=()
for ((i=1; i<"${#arr[@]}"; ++i))
do
        j=`expr $i - 1 `
        arrOut[$i]=`echo "${arr[$i]} ${arr[$j]}" | awk '{a=$1-$2;print a}'`
done

echo ${arrOut[@]}
```